# Jquery validation change input color and add span

Tags: jquery, html, validation, input, colors

I'm trying to customizing Jquery validation.  I happened to change the style of the  error message. How to change style of input? I need to change border color, if success  - green border, if error - red border. And if success - add 
`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:green;">` inside input.
If  if success  - green border - already work.
HTML:

```
<form role="form" action="" id="contact-form" >      
          <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="controls" >       
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="login"  placeholder="LOGIN*"
            maxlength="15">         
            </div>
          </div>    
    </form>
```

CSS:

```
<style>  
    .valid {
    border-color: green;

    }
        label.error {
        font-family:Tahoma;
            font-size:11px;
            color: red;
            padding-left: 8px;          
        }       
  </style>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#contact-form').validate({
        rules: {
          login: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
          }       
        },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            },
            success: function(element) {
                element
                .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
            }
      });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

your css mention that class under label type, yet there are no labels in your html code.
try removing label from css

Comment: Yes, it helped, but only for sucess state. For error i probably need 2 styles, one for label, and one for input.

Comment: 1- make sure your "highlight" function is being called by adding an alert("something") or console.log("something");

2- instead of using add / remove class, try the following:
$(".form-control").css("bolder-color","red");

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the element by class, in this case ".form-input" and adding the class to this specifically. For border you are going to want to add the "border-style" or "border" property.

Comment: "Try selecting the element by class" - how to do it?

Comment: try adding the styling to the form input inside the div, instead of the form-group.